# How do I access the string of an object in my Map?

Tags: java, dictionary, hashmap

Not sure if the question and my actual problem mean the same thing...

I have a Map made out as following:

```
Map<String, Animal> animalMap= new HashMap<String, Animal>;
Animal lion = new Animal();
Animal elephant = new Animal();
Animal cheetah = new Animal();

animalMap.put("lion", lion);
animalMap.put("elephant", elephant);
animalMap.put("cheetah", cheetah);
```

as though I can access "names" of objects
and now I want to print statements like:

"The lion jumped on the elephant!"  or  "The cheetah jumped on the elephant!"

when I call the a function

```
lion.jump(elephant);
```

or

```
cheetah.jump(elephant);
```

.

```
System.out.println("The " + lion + " jumped on the " + elephant + "!");
System.out.println("The " + cheetah + " jumped on the " + elephant + "!");
```

Comment: is it required to have a map?? because you can do a setter and getter method to access the names of each animal objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a HashMap for this. Instead, Java classes can override the toString method. When you do that, the objects will get converted to a string automatically.

```
public class Elephant{
    private String name;

    public Elephant(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "this elephant is named" + this.name;
    }
}
```

If you would add this to your elephant class, the following will call toString on the new elephant object.

```
Elephant e = new Elephant("steve");
System.out.println(e);
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure exactly what you are trying to do, but I think you want to keep a reverse map around so you can do a reverse lookup.

```
Map<Animal,String> animalMapReverse= new HashMap<>();
Animal lion = new Animal();
Animal elephant = new Animal();
Animal cheetah = new Animal();

animalMapReverse.put(lion,"lion");
animalMapReverse.put(elephant,"elephant");
animalMapReverse.put(cheetah,"cheetah");
```

Given this code, you could do:

```
System.out.println("The " + animalMapReverse.get(lion) +
    " jumped on the " + animalMapReverse.get(elephant) + "!");
```

Answer (score 0):

I also don't think you need a `HashMap`.
More like, you need

```
public class Animal {

   private String name;

   public Animal(String name) {
      this.name = name;     
   }

   public String getName() {
      return name;
   }
}
```

And then you you use it like:

```
Animal lion = new Animal("lion");
Animal elephant = new Animal("elephant");
System.out.println(lion.getName() + " jumps over " + elephant.getName());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can retain the map, which will let you look up an Animal by its String name.

But follow Mateva's advice and add a `String name` to your Animal class.

The map could be in Animal, and you can

```
public class Animal {
    private static Map<String,Animal> name2animal = ...;

    private String name;
    public Animal( String n ){
        name = n;
        name2animal.put( n, this );
    }
```

Etc.